# Hibernate creating Composite Key instead of using Identifier

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping, composite-key

I have an Entity FooBar which serves as the @ManyToMany join table for Foo and Bar entities including some additional information.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo_bar")
public class FooBar
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    protected Long id;

    @Column(name = "someInfo", nullable = true)
    private String someInfo;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Foo foo;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Bar bar;


    //getters, setters, and toString()
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
public class Foo
{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
   protected Long id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "foo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   private Set<FooBar> fooBars;

   //Foo has a number of other fields
   @Column(name = "orderIndex", nullable = false)
   private int orderIndex;

   @Column(name = "upgradeDirection", nullable = false)
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   private Order direction;

   @ManyToOne(optional = false)
   private SomeEntity e;


   //getters, setters, and toString()
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "bar")
public class Bar
{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
   protected Long id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bar") //TODO specify a cascade and fetch attribute
   private Set<FooBar> fooBars;

   //Bar contains a number of other fields
   @Column(name = "value", nullable = false)
   private String value;


   //getters, setters, and toString()
}
```

When Hibernate creates the table is has columns 'id', 'someInfo', 'foo_id', and 'bar_id'. 'foo_id' and 'bar_id' are used in as a composite key instead of using the 'id' field, any idea why?

Comment: Do you have a @ManyToMany annotation in Foo or in Bar?

Comment: Foo and Bar both have a @OneToMany relationship with FooBar

Comment: Is it possible that the table was generated before you made some changes to the annotaitons? Do you get the same result if you delete the table and let Hibernate recreate it?

Comment: Yes, I've dropped just foo_bar and dropped the entire database. When Hibernate is creating the table it's making the composite key somehow

Comment: Strange... I don't see what can be causing that in the code you showed us. Maybe it is caused by something you're not showing us.

Comment: Possibly. I'll update the question to include the Foo and Bar objects.